# How to fix a type error when working with stack.top() in the <stack> library in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a function in my linked list that pushes the values of one list into a stack, and then pops off those values into another list.

The problem is, when I try to `std::cout << x`, the `first` stack's topmost element, I get this error:

> c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ostream:682:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

using Item = std::string;

class List {


public:

  class ListNode { //Changed this to public so I could access it. If this was in private how would I accomplish this?
  public:
    Item item;
    ListNode * next;
    ListNode(Item i, ListNode *n=nullptr) {
      item = i;
      next = n;
    }
  };

  ListNode * head;
  ListNode * tail; //Also in private, changed to public, so I could access it. This is the bottom boundry.

  class iterator {
    ListNode *node;
  public:
    iterator(ListNode *n = nullptr) {
      node = n;
    }
    Item& getItem() { return node->item; }
    void next() { node = node->next; }
    bool end() { return node==nullptr; }

    friend class List;
  };

public:
  List() {
    // list is empty
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
  }

  List(const List &other)
  {
    iterator o = other.begin();
    while(!o.end())
      {
         append(o.getItem());   
         o.next();
      }
  }

  bool empty() {
    return head==nullptr;
  }

  // Only declared, here, implemented
  // in List.cpp
  void append(Item a);
  bool remove (Item &copy);

  void insertAfter(iterator, Item);
  void removeAfter(iterator, Item&);

  iterator begin() const {
    return iterator(head);
  }
};


void List::append(Item a) {
  ListNode *node = new ListNode(a);
  if ( head == nullptr ) {
    // empty list
    head = node;
    tail = node;
  } else {
    tail->next = node;
    tail = node;
  }
}

bool List::remove(Item &copy)
{
  if (!empty()) {
    copy = head->item;
    ListNode *tmp = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = tmp;
    if (head==nullptr)
      tail = nullptr;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void List::insertAfter(iterator it, Item item)
{
  if (it.node == nullptr)
    {
      // insert at head
      ListNode *tmp = new ListNode(item,head);
      // if list is empty, set tail to new node
      if (tail==nullptr) {
    tail = tmp;
      }
      // set head to new node
      head = tmp;
    }
  else
    {
      ListNode *tmp = new ListNode(item,it.node->next); 
      it.node->next = tmp;
      // could be a new tail, if so update tail
      if (tail==it.node) {
    tail = tmp;
      }     
    }
}

void List::removeAfter(iterator it, Item& item)
{
  // emtpy list or at tail, just return
  if (it.node == tail) return;

  if (it.node == nullptr)
    {
      ListNode * tmp = head;
      head = head->next;
      delete tmp;
      if (head==nullptr)
    tail = nullptr;
    }
  else
    {
      ListNode *tmp = it.node->next;
      it.node->next = tmp->next;
      delete tmp;
      // could be that it.node is the new nullptr
      if (it.node->next == nullptr)
    tail = it.node;
    }
}

List reverse(const List &l)
{
    List::iterator iter1 = l.begin();
    std::stack<List::ListNode> first; 

    while(!(iter1.end())) {
        first.push(iter1.getItem());
        iter1.next();
    }

    List lthe3;
    int z = first.size();

    for (int i=0; i < z; ++i) {
        List::ListNode x = first.top();
        std::cout << x;
    }

  return l;
}

void printList(List &l) {
  List::iterator i = l.begin();
  while(!i.end()) {
    std::cout << i.getItem() << ", ";    
    i.next();
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  List l;
  l.append("one");
  l.append("two");
  l.append("three");
  l.append("four");

  std::cout << "List in order: ";
  printList(l);

  List l2 = reverse(l);
  std::cout << "List in reverse order: ";
  printList(l2);


  return 0;
}
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, but I'm really close to finishing this function.

Is there any way I could get some feedback?

Comment: Incomplete question. Please manufacture a [mcve]. Also make sure you've implemented  an overload for operator `<<` that will accept a `List::ListNode`.

Comment: Side note: `return l;` seems odd. It's `const`, so reversing it isn't allowed. returning `lthe3` makes more sense if you store the reversed `l` in it. Currently it's not doing much and probably being removed by the compiler.

Comment: Simpler approach: iterate through `l` and insert a copy of each node at the head of `lthe3`.

Comment: What is `List::ListNode` declared as exactly?  Did you implement an overloaded `operator<<(std::ostream&, const List::ListNode&)` for it? Sounds like you did not. BTW, your 2nd loop is not popping items from the stack at all, so it tries to `cout` the same element over and over. You need to add a call to `first.pop()` on each iteration.

Comment: I went ahead and added my full code. Let me know!

Comment: Thank you. This confirms the need for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const List::ListNode&)`. C++ cannot know how to format a data type unless you provide instructions. Many of the Standard data types, `int` and  `std::string` for example, have such a rule, but if you create a brand new class, you're on the hook. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for help on how to do this.

Comment: If you dont mind helping me out again, where would I go about putting that in my code? I have no clue what that even means lol.

Comment: What you really want is `std::cout << x.item;`, but this assumes `Item` is printable. And since it's a `string`, it is!  This will get you going again. The fix may not be as Quick and Dirty  next time, so here's a documentation page from Microsoft on [how to make a simple insertion operator overload.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019). Sooner or later you'll need to know how to write these. Too useful to live without.

Comment: Sometimes creating a [mcve] (didn't someone mention that?) helps you better locate the problem. Find the line that causes the error and strip out as much other code as you can. In this case, you could discover that the linked list is a red herring: `#include <string>

using Item = std::string;

class ListNode {
  public:
    Item item;
    ListNode * next;
    ListNode(Item i, ListNode *n=nullptr) {
      item = i;
      next = n;
    }
  };

int main()
{
  ListNode ln("one");
  std::cout << ln;
}`